# CSS keyframes animations behave as expected on desktop, but showing blank frames/jerky animation on mobile browsers

Tags: html, ios, css, animation, cakeyframeanimation

I am implementing a marquee style banner using css keyframes. It's working great in desktop (see [here](https://queertrip.world) in action), but when I use the same implementation and view the site in mobile browsers the animation delay does not work as expected.

The following occurs on mobile browsers (chrome and safari):

1. I am using a negative animation delay so as to already be halfway through the marquee scroll but instead the text appears halfway up the screen.
2. Blocks of empty space appear then the text fills in after a lag.
3. The animation runs through once then doesn't skips a cycle then continues.
4. The two divs containing text overlap

I have tried using translate3d vs translateX, different animation durations and animation-delays, adding in webkit, ms, moz prefixes, inspecting on the mobile browser.

Example [codepen link](https://codepen.io/cherrihart/pen/BayaadB)

Would appreciate any guidance!

```
<div class="marquee">
  <div class="marqueeScroll">
    <span>Countdown to our first city guide</span>
    <span>•</span>
    <span>
      NYC comes out in 10 days 4 hours 30 minutes 2 seconds
    </span>
    <span>•</span>
    <span>Countdown to our first city guide</span>
    <span>•</span>
    <span>
      NYC comes out in 10 days 4 hours 30 minutes 2 seconds
    </span>
    <span>•</span>
  </div>
  <div class="marqueeScroll2">
    <span>Countdown to our first city guide</span>
    <span>•</span>
    <span>
      NYC comes out in 10 days 4 hours 30 minutes 2 seconds
    </span>
    <span>•</span>
    <span>Countdown to our first city guide</span>
    <span>•</span>
    <span>
      NYC comes out in 10 days 4 hours 30 minutes 2 seconds
    </span>
    <span>•</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
.marquee {
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;

  height: 39px;
  width: 100vh;

  right: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;

  -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg) translateY(-100vh);
  transform: rotate(270deg) translateY(-100vh);
  transform-origin: top right;

  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

.marquee:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.marquee span {
  padding-right: 18px;
}

.marqueeScroll, .marqueeScroll2 {
  height: 20px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-size: 10px;
  display: block;

  -webkit-animation-duration: 70s;
  -moz-animation-duration: 70s;
  -o-animation-duration: 70s;
  animation-duration: 70s;

  -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
  -moz-animation-timing-function: linear;
  -o-animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-timing-function: linear;

  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -o-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

.marqueeScroll {
  -webkit-animation-name: marquee;
  -moz-animation-name: marquee;
  -o-animation-name: marquee;
  animation-name: marquee;

  -webkit-animation-delay: -35s;
  -moz-animation-delay: -35s;
  -o-animation-delay: -35s;
  animation-delay: -35s;
}

.marqueeScroll2 {
  -webkit-animation-name: marquee2;
  -moz-animation-name: marquee2;
  -o-animation-name: marquee2;
  animation-name: marquee2;

  -webkit-animation-delay: -70s;
  -moz-animation-delay: -70s;
  -o-animation-delay: -70s;
  animation-delay: -70s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes marquee {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes marquee {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
  }
}

@-o-keyframes marquee {
  0% {
    -o-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
  }
  100% {
    -o-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
  }
}

@keyframes marquee {
  0% {
    transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes marquee2 {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-200%, 0, 0);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0%, 0, 0);
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes marquee2 {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: translate3d(-200%, 0, 0);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: translate3d(0%, 0, 0);
  }
}

@-o-keyframes marquee2 {
  0% {
    -o-transform: translate3d(-200%, 0, 0);
  }
  100% {
    -o-transform: translate3d(0%, 0, 0);
  }
}

@keyframes marquee2 {
  0% {
    transform: translate3d(-200%, 0, 0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate3d(0%, 0, 0);
  }
}
```